# HTML Service - Dropdown option list from GSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-caja

Into Google Apps script and HTML service

> ```
> Code.gs 
> function doGet() {
>   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTMLUI').evaluate()
>   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
> }
> ```

Here is HTML

```
HTMLUI.html

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
<?
  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Avt7ejriwlxudGZfV2xJUGJZLXktQ2RhQU1uRUgtaXc").getSheetByName("MRF Tab");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("C3:C"+lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
?>
</script>
<select>
<? for (var i = 0; i < sourcedata.length; ++i) { ?>
<option><?!= sourcedata[i] ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

I had this code in one of my project (and a lot more code) which basically captures information form the sheet and add it to the options (dropdown) in select, but when trying this same code in new project this isnt working, any ideas what am I missing.

At present the result displayed is a dropdown box with `<?!=sourcedata[i]?>`

How can I correct this. Any help please.

EDIT:---

Please have a look @ comment no 3 for link to a spreadsheet and some workaround with it...

Comment: "At present the result displayed is a dropdown box with..." what? The suspense is killing me! Is the lastRow > 3?

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad...I think because of the arrows, question mark it wasnt visible, I have amended the code to make them visible now...Pasting some more info please wait..

Comment: Ok...here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak8UXE3yTEiQdFJRMS1yTkpHLTE1NmZsaXdhVnhIQUE#gid=0) to spreadsheet..there are 2 doGet function, if I publish using the first comment it works, however it doesnt work from the second doGet...I have many files which I have seperated and connected using include..any help here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you describe are the result of *nested* templated HTML - it's clear that the evaluator isn't designed to handle it, so the unevaluated scriptlets are being shown as text.

You're using templated HTML in `test.html` to include templated HTML from `HTMLUI.html`, and the `include()` function tries to treat the content of `HTMLUI.html` as regular (non-templated) HTML source.

One way around this would be to use a version of `include()` specifically for templated html. Put this in your gs file:

```
function includeTemplate(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
      .getContent();
}
```

Your `test.html` then becomes:

```
<?!= includeTemplate('HTMLUI'); ?>
```

This will accomplish what you're trying in your example. To do so, though, you're losing some of the capabilities of templated html, as you will not have the opportunity to push variables to the template.

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad(Ustad)....you are great..."You will not have the opportunity to push variables to the template" - please can you explain what does this mean...Sorry still learning....

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-templates#pushing_variables_to_templates